# Recycler view cannot be at the bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to add a horizantal recyclerview at the bottom in linearlayout but it always starts from top of linearlayout , here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"

            android:elevation="100dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
            app:cardElevation="66dp"

            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.076"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/menu_image_view"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/menu_icon" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/frameLayout2"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/menu_image_view"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/medfast_linear_layout"

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layoutDirection="ltr"

                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="visible">

                        <com.plus.medfast.customViews.views.CustomRegularTextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/be_healthy" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/zinc_linear_layout"

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layoutDirection="ltr"

                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1.3"
                            android:src="@drawable/medfast_word_only" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="-2dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1.7"
                            android:gravity="center">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_deal" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/zinc" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.9">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.1"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/medfast_ads_image_view"
                                android:layout_width="40dp"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="left"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/medfast_ads_text_view"
                                android:layout_width="15dp"
                                android:layout_height="15dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="top|end"


                                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/circle_view_white_solid"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="10"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="10dp"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/medfast_ads_image_view"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/medfast_ads_image_view"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
                    </FrameLayout>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.3"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/normal_ads_image_view"
                                android:layout_width="30dp"
                                android:layout_height="40dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="left"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_notification"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/normal_ads_text_view"
                                android:layout_width="15dp"
                                android:layout_height="15dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="top|end"

                                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/circle_view_white_solid"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="10"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="10dp"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/normal_ads_image_view"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/normal_ads_image_view"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/focused_service_name_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/services_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:clipToPadding="false" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.plus.medfast.customViews.views.CustomBoldTextView
            android:id="@+id/focused_service_name_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_maps_navigation_drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/core_activity_navigation_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

but the result as shown bellow, i need the recyclerview be in bottom because i wan't to translate Y axis of the view to up

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Everything in my xml is well written.
after adding marginTop=20 to the recycler view item it works well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_view_red"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/service_image_view"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <com.plus.medfast.customViews.views.CustomBoldTextView
            android:id="@+id/service_name_text_view"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```